# How to integrate Okta SignIn widget and SAML SSO with a Angularjs SPA?

Tags: angularjs, saml-2.0, okta, okta-api

I've been trying to implement Okta SSO using SAML with my AngularJS SPA (using the Okta Sign-in widget) with no success.

The widget works OK by itself (without the SAML integration, just the widget). I'm able to authenticate my user's credentials, set the session cookie and redirect to my app homepage.

I followed the instructions from this link ([Okta SignIn Widget with SAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170464/okta-signin-widget-with-saml)) to integrate SAML with no luck.

The widget is able to authenticate my user's credentials but when the IDP (in this case the Okta site) redirects to my app using the "App Embed Link" I got a blank screen and I can see a POST to my app URL with the SAML assertion as a parameter with status 405 (method not allowed).

I'm really lost about this, and the Okta documentation is kind of loose around this matter. Some of my doubts are:

1. When configuring my app in the Okta admin: What should I put on the
   "Single sign on URL" field? my app login page URL?, or, an endpoint
   URL on my backend in charge of processing the SAML assertion?
2. Where should I place my Okta app's X.509 Certificate and IDP login URL?

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to get SAML to work with a JavaScript Single Page Application, it isn't the ideal way to implement Single Sign-On.

I suggest using OpenID Connect to add SSO capabilities to your AngularJS app. Here is a sample project showing [how to use Okta's Sign-In Widget with AngularJS](https://github.com/jmelberg-okta/okta-oidc-angular-1-samples).

Unfortunatly, (and confusingly) the StackOverflow question you were looking at was about how to use the Okta Sign-In Widget to log in to an *existing* SAML application. It isn't possible to use the Okta Sign-In Widget to support SAML.

If you *have* to implement SAML in your AngularJS app, then you will need to add SAML support to the backend for your AngularJS app. The flow would look something like this:

1. After authenticating with Okta, your browser will POST the `SAMLResponse` to your backend.
2. Your backend will validate the `SAMLResponse`.
3. If the `SAMLResponse` is valid, your backend will establish a session with your AngularJS app.

Comment: I have reached till Point#2, but not sure how to take my user from Backend to Angular app. Basically, I want the user to be redirected to a Particular URL once SAML is validated.
I am using WebAPI which i think is not capable for URL redirection.
Can you please help how is that possible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Web API, however the basics are to validate SAML on the backend, establish a session for the user, then return the HTML for the Angular app.

Comment: Web API is a WebService which can not call or establish a connection from its own side.

Comment: I think JoëlFranusic is correct that you need to return HTML as is @CuriousBuddy in that Web.API is not going to work.  I've created a Node.js Express simple solution for the backend here https://stackoverflow.com/q/53603554/358574 I'll see if that can send html to the user connecting the angular spa to the authentication flow.  I'll need to change the code a bit to store the token and then communicate it via the HTML emit to the spa.